# Queued Events in Laravel 4: Event::flusher() method not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

According to the [Laravel 4 Documentation on queued Events](http://laravel.com/docs/events#queued-events), I tried to register an event flusher this way:

```
Event::flusher('foo.bar', function($data)
{
    Mail::send(array('emails.notification', 'emails.notification_text'), array('content' => $data), function($message)
    {
        $message
            ->to('email@example.com', 'My Name')
            ->bcc('test@example.com')
            ->subject('Message from Listener');
    });    
});
```

But I am getting the following error upon loading of the script:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::flusher()

I also couldn't find this method in the source codes of L4. But when I change this from `Event::flusher()` to `Event::listen()`, everything works as expected.

So my guess is, that the documentation isn't up to date and the `Event::flusher()` method has been dropped, since `Event::listen()` does the same work. Or are there any differences between those two methods and I have an error in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your libraries using:

```
$ composer update
```

If that doesn't work, let us know what your `composer.json` file looks like - you might be using a beta version if the framework. It was updated very often before the first stable release.